# how can I simulate cpu and memory stress powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm doing a cpu and memory stress test on windows server 2016 and 2019
When I run it on the virtual server the results are successful  100% load
Not enough load occurs when I run it on physical server
How can i solve this situation

```
**cpu_stress**

    <#
    .EXAMPLE
    .\cpu_stress.ps1
    
    This will execute the script against all cores
    
    .DESCRIPTION
    #>
    
    # CPUs in the machine
    $cpus=$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
    # Lower the thread so it won't overwhelm the system for other things
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.Priority = 'Lowest'
    
    #####################
    # perfmon counters for CPU
    $Global:psPerfCPU = new-object System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Processor","% Processor Time","_Total")
    $psPerfCPU.NextValue() | Out-Null
    
    
    $StartDate = Get-Date
    Write-Output "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=  Stress Machine Started: $StartDate =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-="
    Write-Warning "This script will saturate all available CPUs in the machine"
    Write-Warning "To cancel execution of all jobs, close the PowerShell Host Window (or terminate the remote session)"
    Write-Output "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=  CPUs in box: $cpus =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= "
    
    
    
    # This will stress the CPU
    foreach ($loopnumber in 1..$cpus){
      Start-Job -ScriptBlock{
      $result = 1
          foreach ($number in 1..0x7FFFFFFF){
              $result = $result * $number
          }# end foreach
      }# end Start-Job
    }# end foreach
    
    Write-Output "Created sub-jobs to consume the CPU"
    # Ask the user if they want to clear out RAM, if so we will continue
    Read-Host -Prompt "Press any key to stop the JOBs CTRL+C to quit"
    
    Write-Output "Clearing CPU Jobs"
    Receive-Job *
    Stop-Job *
    Remove-Job *
    
    $EndDate = Get-Date
    Write-Output "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= Stress Machine Complete: $EndDate =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-="
```

Comment: why are you reinventing the wheel? [*grin*] there are well proven utils for that kind of thing ... i recommend you pick one and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows Sysinternals CpuStres and Testlimit.

Comment: cmkync's question is valid because in certain organizations the security setting is high and the Internet is not allowed to download the proven simulation software. Therefore, we have to use a powershell script.